# EXP() in BigQuery returns floating-point error

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following query:

```
SELECT EXP(col) FROM `project.dataset.tablename`;
```

Where `col` is `FLOAT`. However, I get this error: `Error: Floating point error in function: EXP`.

I've tried `EXP()` with dummy data, and it works. For example:

```
SELECT EXP(col) FROM (
    SELECT 1. as col UNION ALL
    SELECT 2. as col);
```

Why do I get a floating-point error with actual data and how do I work around it? I've tried such things as `EXP(CAST(col as FLOAT64))` and `EXP(ROUND(col, n))`, but I still get the same error.

Comment: job id in case someone can debug it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you are working with numbers larger than 709.7827.

Weird number, but even in Fortran docs:

> EXP(X)
>
> Exponential.
>
> X must be less than or equal to 709.7827.
>
> http://sc.tamu.edu/IBM.Tutorial/docs/Compilers/xlf_8.1/html/lr277.HTM

This because numbers get too large after e^709.7827.

Comment: `weird number` is not that weird one :o) it comes off of `1024 x LN(2)` where 1024 for sure looks much more familiar to all :o)

Comment: Welcome to 2016. We didn't know that then

Comment: we all are learning. and btw since I jumped into world of GCP in 2013 - it is learning on steroids - you guys are crazy with pace of delivering cool new stuff - thank you!!!

Comment: I think I missed a :o).  :o)

Answer (score 1):

Run the query:

```
SELECT MAX(col)
FROM project.dataset.tablename;
```

It will probably then be obvious why you are getting an overflow error.  You can work around it by using a `case`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN col < ?? THEN EXP(col) END)
FROM project.dataset.tablename;
```

I could suggest a value, but it is probably obvious from your application -- say something larger than 10 or 100 might just be unreasonable.